# Grid layout from Array of JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I don't really know how to describe this, but basically I am rendering checkbox items, but I don't want them in a list format. Nor will I know how many elements may exist within the Array of JSON Objects.

I can easily create a list such as:

```
item.value1
item.value2
item.value3
etc
```

but I could have 3 or 300 items in the JSON object, so this is silly.

What I'd like to do is

```
item.value1 | item.value2 | item.value3
item.value4 | item.value5 | item.value6
etc
```

Without needing to know how many Objects are in the Array. The Array would look like:

```
[
  {
     id: 1,
     value: column1
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     value: column2
  },
  // etc
];
```

The html will simply be:

```
<label data-ng-bind="item.value1"></label> <input type="checkbox" data-ng-bind="item.id1" />
<label data-ng-bind="item.value2"></label> <input type="checkbox" data-ng-bind="item.id2" />
<label data-ng-bind="item.value3"></label> <input type="checkbox" data-ng-bind="item.id3" />
```

I'd like to do this in generic javascript. i know there is a way but I can't remember what it is, or what to call it for searching lol

I also don't want to use a "plugin" because I don't need that much code to write yet another scope object, when I already have the scope objects, or for that matter, adding a verbose controller, module, directive or factory, when this is a nice generic 'if count >=3 then render masonry/grid view'

Comment: IMHO, In bootstrap you can use `col-md-4` ;).

Comment: I know right? I just realized that myself. I think I've been coding too long today lol

Answer (score 0):

> You can use ng-repeat for this approach.If u have your array in $scope.array object on controller.For eg.

```
 $scope.array=[
  {
     id: 1,
     value: column1
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     value: column2
  },
  // etc
];
```

> Your view code-

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
<div class="col-lg-4"><label data-ng-bind="item.value"></label></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"><label data-ng-bind="item.value"></label></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"><label data-ng-bind="item.value"></label></div>
</div>
```

> Please note I m using bootstrap to show 3 items in a row

Comment: hey, actually I only needed to do
```
class="col-md-3"
```

I had been coding for 15 hours straight and simply forgot about that... I was already pulling it from the scope, and besides, i'm not using partials cuz partials are for people who can't code - I'm using document.createFragment and injecting/compiling the element, so I don't have to write it a 1000 times :)

all good - i was just tired lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
  {
     id: 1,
     value: 'column1'
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     value: 'column2'
  },
 {
     id: 3,
     value: 'column3'
  },
  {
     id: 4,
     value: 'column4'
  },
   {
     id: 1,
     value: 'column5'
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     value: 'column6'
  },
 {
     id: 3,
     value: 'column7'
  },
  {
     id: 4,
     value: 'column8'
  },
];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-switch on="$index % 3">
     <div style="float:left">
        {{item.value}}
     </div>
    
     <div ng-switch-when="2"><br></div>
   </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: hey
I only needed to wrote class=col-md-3 
i had been coding for 15 hours straight and forgot

also I don't use partials. I inject/compile elements, so I don't need to ever write any element more than once, and it's nothing but a directive, or service injection call.

html is unnecessary in the 21st century. Code can write it for me.